# don't understand how the below code tells python to pick the highest number inputted on the list

Tags: python

I am going through this training in Udemy done by Angela Yu.  She has explained the below code but I cant seem to understand how the code actually picks up the highest number using the code below. I am a beginner and looking for someone to clarify each step of the process.

```
#  Don't change the code below 
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
  student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)
#  Don't change the code above 

#Write your code below this row 

highest_score = 0

for score in student_scores:
    if score > highest_score:
        highest_score = score
```

print(score)

Comment: Looking at multiple mountain peaks from a distant point how do you say which one is the highest. You are only allowed to look from left to right.

Comment: `if score > highest_score:`  . . .  then  . . . `highest_score = score` . . . this is the part that keeps selecting the highest score.

Comment: Someone calls you up and reads you a list of scores. You know you need to find the highest, but you can't ask the person to repeat a score, you can't write the scores down, and you can't remember them all. The strategy you would probably adopt to find the highest score is what this code does.

Comment: I hope the input values are not all negative. Did you consider using max() ?

Comment: @DarkKnight student score never be below zero.

Comment: @FT How do you know that? There are no checks in the code!

Comment: @DarkKnight to be honest, we were restricted from using max() since we are learning how "for loops" works at the technical layer.  Max was an easy way of given us the answer.

Comment: @ft I dont think a score would ever be below 0?  the code wont allow it unless someone put a -int.  unless you have something else in mind?

Comment: @DarkKnight how would checks make a difference?  this is not a smart ass answer. truly trying to understand.

Comment: @DarkKnight I agree with you. This code should start with `extreme negative number` as initial maximum  value in order to make sure what ever number user inputs is captured. What I meant by score never be below zero is all about score not about user input. User can provide characters too right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for score in student_scores:
    if score > highest_score:
        highest_score = score
```

so we would take this code step by step, first step would be the first line.

```py
for score in student_scores:
```

so inside the for loop, we loop throughout all of the variable, in this example: student_scores, and we save the input we get in score

so for example:

```
TempList = ["foo", "bar"]

for i in TempList:
    print(i)
```

and the output would be:

```
foo
bar
```

because we're looping through every item in the list, so first would be "foo" because its the first one, and then it would be "bar" because its second and so on,

```
    if score > highest_score:
```

then we're checking if score is bigger than the highest_score, and the score variable is the current item from the list, and since the variable highest_score is set to 0, if somebody has bigger than 0 it comes to the next step, if not it checks another item in the list, if the highest_score would be another number, score variable would need to be bigger than the highest_score to proceed to another instruction,

```
        highest_score = score
```

and now if the score is bigger than the highest_score we just set variable highest_score to the variable score, so then we would go through the next loop and we would do the same as last but we'll check if score is bigger than the current highest_score,

and lastly:

```
print(score)
```

You can see that it doesn't have the amount of spaces that does other code have, it's because it's outside the for loop, so it would run after the for loop ends, and if it ends we just print the score, but there's an error because we cannot use the variable score outside of the for loop, so it would need to be:

```py
print(highest_score)
```

I know its long but I tried to make it as detailed as possible

you can also just view this article about Python For Loop From w3schools, it's trusted by me domain and you can teach yourself some pretty basic begginer, and medium stuff but there can be also some hard stuff if you need them like machine learning, but there you go, the tutorial and documentation about for loops:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: You did an amazing job!  I really appreciate the help.  its funny because I see what is going on but for some reason looking at the code it just didn't makes sense.   I see the code "for loop" is looping through all the variables and check which one is greater.  if its greater then it stores that "true" into highest_score.   then little by little keeping the highest true integer.  The problem I am having is that i can't read that by reading the code.  because in my head having a variable repeat itself was just hurting my brain lol.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't exactly understand what you mean by saying "having a variable repeat itself",